# Show these 2 expressions are logically equivalent

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Show that $ (p\land r)\oplus(\lnot p\land q) $ and  $ (p\lor q)\land (\lnot p \lor r) $ are logically equivalent.

I have some trouble with this type of question, especially when it comes to $\oplus$. After I tried to rewrite the expression with $\land$ and $\lor$, I got lost.

Answer (score 0):

A routine way would be to make 8 substitutions of $\ (p\ q\ r)\ $
by $\ (\pm\ \pm\ \pm).\ $

Another way could be by checking $\ p:=0,\ $ then $\ p:=1.\ $ In the first case we get $\ q\ $ for both expressions; and in the other substitution ($\ p:=1$) gives $\ r.$

A third way convenient way is close to your suggestion but I would
prefer to have the more algebraic combination of $\ \wedge\ $
and $\ \oplus$ -- then you computing like in a commutative ring, and you'd enjoy obvious additional advantages.

Altogether, the 2nd method is here the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

$a\oplus b$ is usually defined as $(a\lor b)\land(\lnot a\lor\lnot b)$

Use that.$$(p\land r)\oplus(\lnot p\land q)~=~((p\land r)\lor(\lnot p\land q))\land(\lnot(p\land r)\lor\lnot(\lnot p\land q))$$

Then apply deMorgan's rules and distribution …

$$(p\land r)\oplus(\lnot p\land q)~=~(p\lor \lnot p)\land(p\lor q)\land(r\lor\lnot p)\land(r\lor q)\land((\lnot p\lor\lnot r)\lor(p\lor\lnot q))$$